# RStudio learnr package error "ERROR: compilation failed for package 'backports'"

Tags: r, package

First question on StackOverflow. I will try to be clear.

I just installed

1. R 4.0.1 for Windows 10
2. RStudio (RStudio 1.3.959) for Windows 10

I tried to install learnr package, which required many other packages. The console prints toward the end:

---

- installing *source* package 'backports' ...
  ** package 'backports' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** using staged installation
  ** libs
  "c:/rtools40/mingw64/bin/"gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign -c dotsElt.c -o dotsElt.o
  /bin/sh: c:/rtools40/mingw64/bin/gcc: No such file or directory
  make: *** [dotsElt.o] Error 127
  ERROR: compilation failed for package 'backports'
- removing 'C:/Users/micha/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/backports'
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘backports’ had non-zero exit status
- installing *source* package 'isoband' ...
  ** package 'isoband' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** using staged installation
  ** libs
  "c:/rtools40/mingw64/bin/"g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'C:/Users/micha/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/testthat/include'        -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign -c clip-lines.cpp -o clip-lines.o
  /bin/sh: c:/rtools40/mingw64/bin/g++: No such file or directory
  make: *** [clip-lines.o] Error 127
  ERROR: compilation failed for package 'isoband'
- removing 'C:/Users/micha/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/isoband'
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘isoband’ had non-zero exit status
  ERROR: dependency 'isoband' is not available for package 'ggplot2'
- removing 'C:/Users/micha/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/ggplot2'
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status

---

Is it an internal issue, or a problem with the packages? Should I contact the package maintainer for 'backports', 'isoband', 'ggplot2', re-install R and/or RStudio, or something else?

Comment: What is the code you used to install learnr?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you run that on Windows and want to install `learnr` from the source (it means that you have to compile these packages). However, some packages need additional tools to compile on Windows. These tools are provided in official [RTools for Windows](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/), so install that first and try again.

And sometimes you can install the binary versions of the packages rather than the source. Then you don't need to compile:

```
install.packages("learnr", type = "binary")
```

Comment: That helped with the package tibble. Had the same problem after upgrading to R 4.0.1 on Windows. Thank you!